# S3 Presigned Upload URL to support multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading, region, pre-signed-url

currently my app can upload images to a bucket in APSE1(singapore) and my app is mostly used in south east asia, so everything is pretty fast. I am wondering how can I support multiple regions? Let's say I want to also get people in the US to use my app, right now, their uploads will be slow since the bucket location is in singapore. I know that there's this S3 feature to replicate data across regions, but I wonder how I can detect the user location and get presigned upload url to closest bucket for that particular user? Right now I hardcode it to singapore... Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably putting [a CloudFront distribution in front of the bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/).

That said, have you benchmarked this? My understanding is that latency is more of a concern for a flurry of small requests than it would be for something like one or just a couple of large image uploads.